# How to create a pattern grid for tiles with Phtoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns

I am trying to create a pattern for tiles.

So, I have a specific width and height and I want to fill it with rectangles and leave space for grout.

Then I want to fill every rectangle with the same image.

Here's a rough sketch:

[image]

Comment: Hi illys, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

I would do this in **Illustrator**.

Simply draw a rectangle the size you want, then choose `Object > Path > Split Into Grid` and enter the number of tiles horizontally and vertically (rows and columns) along with any gutters (grout) area.

[image]

Copy and paste into Photoshop if that's where you need it.

As far as I'm aware, the *only* similar feature in Photoshop...

If you *must* use **only Photoshop**, you can create a **[guide layout](http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2014/10/new-guide-layout-and-new-guide-from-shape-in-photoshop-cc.html)** - which will essentially set up guides in a similar manner without actual paths or shapes - then use that to draw shapes.

Beyond this, for *only* Photoshop, and for any version prior to Photoshop CC,  you'll need to measure and manually figure out tile sizes.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution using photoshop

1. start new square document with the tile dimension + the grout space
2. draw the square tile and leave the grout space around the rectangle or in the middle of the document.
3. before making the tiles test is by choosing `Filers > others > offset` and choose some values that is smaller than the original document dimensions. (in my example my document where 500px square .. I do offset from 300px).

[image]

4. now you are ready to make a pattern by choosing `Edit > define pattern...` and type a proper name for your new pattern.
5. now you can see your new pattern in the pattern swatch and you can use it in any document.

[image]